# Scrollview flashing when inflating view and calling scrollBy

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I am developing an Android application where an activity displays content in a scrollview. At the top of the content there is a placeholder for an image to be displayed. The image is downloaded from the Internet and may take a few seconds until it is ready to be displayed. The image placeholder is initially empty. When the image is downloaded, it is dynamically added to the placeholder.

Initially I had the following problem.

- The user starts the activity and scrolls down
- The image starts to download in the background. When available, it is added to the placeholder
- When the image is added to the placeholder, the contents of the scrollview change and the user experience is disrupted by the unwanted scrolling that occurs

To fix this, I added code to adjust the scroll position once the image view is added to the placeholder. The problem with this is that a flickering is caused on the scrollview during the display-image and adjust-scrollview process. The reason is that the scrollBy function is called from a runnable. Calling scrollBy outside the runnable does not cause flickering but the scroll position is incorrect - the reason for this is that there is not enough time for the items on the scroll view to recalculate/measure their dimensions/heights.

Here is a sample application the illustrates this problem:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ScrollView scrollView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scrollview);

        startImageDownload();
        simulateImageScroll();
    }

    private void simulateImageScroll() {
        // scroll to the bottom of the scroll view
        scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                scrollView.scrollTo(0, scrollView.getMaxScrollAmount());
            }
        });
    }

    private void startImageDownload() {
        Handler handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
        // simulate a delay for the image download to illustrate the flashing problem in the scrollview
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                displayImage("");
            }
        }, 2000);

    }

    // when the image is downloaded we add it to the image container
    private void displayImage(String imageFilename) {
        // dynamically create an image and add it to the image container layout
        RelativeLayout container = findViewById(R.id.imageContainer);
        ImageView img = new ImageView(this);

        // image should be loaded from the given filename - for now use a solid background and fixed height
        img.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 500);
        container.addView(img, params);

        adjustScrolling(container);
    }

    private void adjustScrolling(RelativeLayout container) {
        // adjust scroll if the image is loaded before the current content
        if (scrollView.getScrollY() > container.getTop()) {
            container.measure(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            final int amountToScroll = container.getMeasuredHeight();

            // the following does not cause flickering but scrolls to the wrong position
            //scrollView.scrollBy(0, amountToScroll);

            // adjust the scrollview so that it keeps the current view unchanged
            scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // this causes flickering but scrolls to the correct position
                    scrollView.scrollBy(0, amountToScroll);
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the layout file:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/imageContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#aa0000" >

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#aa0000" >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="128dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#aa0000" >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="128dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#aa0000" >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="3"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="128dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#aa0000" >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="4"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="128dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Comment: The problem is that the imageview will resize as the image loads and therefore will cause a flicker. I think you need to try a different approach. E.g:
a) Try animating the view when the image loads. This will not be the ideal answer, but it will make the ux better.
b) You can also download the image, but not add it to the container until the user scrolls to the top. 
These are a few suggestions if you don't want to keep the image height fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited: 
Currently, your layout is flickering, because adding blue view cause redraw layout (and scroll). So scroll occurred once, and next you scrolled to the position you want. That's the second moving.

To solve this problem, you need to know how android draws view.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html

Simply, `onMeasure()` - `onLayout()` - `onDraw()`. And you can add your layout code between `onLayout()` and `onDraw()`, by `ViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener()`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html

ps: I still recommend using nice and lovely image library, Picasso.

Fixed code is: Set scroll before `draw()` called. By this, you can draw only once.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ScrollView scrollView;
    int amountToScroll = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
        scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                scrollView.scrollBy(0, amountToScroll);
                amountToScroll = 0;
            }
        });
        startImageDownload();
        simulateImageScroll();
    }

    private void simulateImageScroll() {
        // scroll to the bottom of the scroll view
        scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                scrollView.scrollTo(0, scrollView.getMaxScrollAmount());
            }
        });
    }

    private void startImageDownload() {
        Handler handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
        // simulate a delay for the image download to illustrate the flashing problem in the scrollview
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                displayImage("");
            }
        }, 2000);

    }

    // when the image is downloaded we add it to the image container
    private void displayImage(String imageFilename) {
        // dynamically create an image and add it to the image container layout
        RelativeLayout container = findViewById(R.id.imageContainer);
        ImageView img = new ImageView(this);

        // image should be loaded from the given filename - for now use a solid background and fixed height
        img.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 500);
        container.addView(img, params);

        adjustScrolling(container);
    }

    private void adjustScrolling(RelativeLayout container) {
        // adjust scroll if the image is loaded before the current content
        if (scrollView.getScrollY() > container.getTop()) {
            container.measure(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            amountToScroll = container.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
    }
}
```

---

I strongly recommend using **Picasso.** http://square.github.io/picasso/

This one line will fix all of your problem.

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

You can load your local image file or network image (url) into your imageView.

In your case, remove both `startImageDownload()` and `simulateImageScroll()`, and on `onResume()`, call `displayImage()`.

Fixed displayImage():

```
private void displayImage(String imageFilename) {
    // dynamically create an image and add it to the image container layout
    RelativeLayout container = findViewById(R.id.imageContainer);
    ImageView img = new ImageView(this);

    // image should be loaded from the given filename - for now use a solid background and fixed height
    img.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 500);
    container.addView(img, params);
    Picasso.with(this).load(imageFilename).into(img);

    adjustScrolling(container);
}
```

**Or,** if you want to solve this problem directly for academic reasons,

1. Do not adjust your scroll. It seems that it is not a real solution to use `scrollBy` to fix your problem. The real cause is the code that cause the UI to redraw. May be calling `invalidate()` or something like that.
2. Adding ImageView programmatically is not a good idea. Because your RecyclerView or ViewHolder of ListView cannot reuse the view, so it cause degrade performance. If you can avoid it, do that. (eg. use xml)
3. It seems that adding your ImageView to imageContainer is real problem. imageContainer has `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` property, and this means it has no fixed height, it depends on it's own child. Try to change to fixed value, for example: `android:layout_height="500dp"`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Unfortunately, they do not solve the problem. The time it takes to download the image is not the reason for the problem - I tried with a local image and the problem is the same. Regarding the second solution, again, it does not work since the height of the image is not known at design time so it cannot be set manually. The problem is clearly that the scrollview refreshes twice and that causes the flashing.

Comment: @user501223 Oh, that's too bad. How about set height of ImageView fixed? You can centercrop or scaleXY.

Comment: That is not an option. I do not want to set the image height manually. Thanks anyway

Comment: Anyway, creating a simple example that can reproduce issue is a good approach.

Comment: All the code is posted above. Create a new application and replace the application and application layout files with the ones I posted above. Run the application and it will automatically scroll to the bottom and load a dummy image in 2000 millis - this will cause the flashing of the screen.

Comment: if you would load your image in picasso by resize() i think your problem will be solved. you may try it once

Comment: As I said before, it is not the loading of the image that is the problem - the problem comes from the fact that the scrollview is updated twice in a short amount of time; once when the imageview is added/loaded and another time when the scroll position is adjusted.

Comment: @user501223 I edited my answer, and it is tested code.

Answer (score 0):

Well first if it's a single image on top then you don't have to create imageview dynamically just use it inside your XML file without Relative-layout. set to an default image. Use Image-View with adjustViewBounds="true" and scaleType="fitCenter" then you don't have to worry about the image scaling.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@id/img"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

you can use Picasso http://square.github.io/picasso/ library as suggested by "Stanley Kou" for loading the image.

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion is to use Progress Bar, Start the Progress bar when image starts downloading and hide it  once the image load is complete then let the user see the activity.

```
  <ProgressBar
  android:id="@+id/indeterminateBar"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

For more details, please check -

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

Comment: Thanks, but still this does not solve the problem. What I was looking for is basically a way to make the scrollview to not update its contents until after the scroll position is adjusted (maybe a solution that involves extending the default scrollview class). As I said above the user may scroll down and start reading some text - what I am looking for is to have content be dynamically added above the current scroll position (in the non-visible part of the scrollview) and at the same time, keep the current view the same, so that the user is not distracted.